# Remove object elements where the element equal elements in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, nested-loops

I have this object

```
 var _identLayer = {                         
                          id: layerIndex,                                                  // Layer ID
                          label: opLayersMap.layerInfos[i].name,              // Layer Name
                          zoomscale: "2000",
                          forcescale: true
                      };
```

and the result of `console.log(_identLayer);`

[Object { id: 1, label: "site1", zoomscale: "2000", forcescale: true }

Object { id: 2, label: "site2", zoomscale: "2000", forcescale: true }

Object { id: 3, label: "site3", zoomscale: "2000", forcescale: true }

Object { id: 4, label: "site4", zoomscale: "2000", forcescale: true }

Object { id: 5, label: "site5", zoomscale: "2000", forcescale: true }

Object { id: 6, label: "site6", zoomscale: "2000", forcescale: true }

Object { id: 7, label: "site7", zoomscale: "2000", forcescale: true }

Object { id: 8, label: "site8", zoomscale: "2000", forcescale: true }

Object { id: 9, label: "site9", zoomscale: "2000", forcescale: true }]

also I have this array

```
var tempArr=["site1","site3","site5","site7"]
```

Now I want the result of `console.log(_identLayer);` all the elements in `_identLayer` except where `_identLayer.label` equal to the elements of `tempArr` array

I tred this but it's not working

```
var tempArr=["site1","site3","site5","site7"]

                      
                      for (var a = 0; a < tempArr.length; a++) {
                              if (_identLayer.label != tempArr[a]) {
                                  console.log("_identLayer")
                                  console.log(_identLayer);
                          } 
                      }
```

Comment: You are just checking with single object label you need to loop through the other array also ! Also is _identLayer an object of array ?

Comment: is `_identLayer` an array of objects?

Comment: @RameshReddy yes it is an array of objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .includes() for this case:

example:

```
var tempArr=["site1","site3","site5","site7"]:

if (tempArr.includes(_identLayer.label) == false) {
    console.log(_identLayer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to exclude the elements that you don't need in resultant array:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, label: "site1", zoomscale: "2000", forcescale: true },
  { id: 2, label: "site2", zoomscale: "2000", forcescale: true },
  { id: 3, label: "site3", zoomscale: "2000", forcescale: true },
  { id: 4, label: "site4", zoomscale: "2000", forcescale: true },
  { id: 5, label: "site5", zoomscale: "2000", forcescale: true },
  { id: 6, label: "site6", zoomscale: "2000", forcescale: true },
  { id: 7, label: "site7", zoomscale: "2000", forcescale: true },
  { id: 8, label: "site8", zoomscale: "2000", forcescale: true },
  { id: 9, label: "site9", zoomscale: "2000", forcescale: true }
];

const filterBy = ["site1", "site3", "site5", "site7"];

const result = data.filter(({ label }) => !filterBy.includes(label));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi I just assumed that data structure to be an array. However in case if it is not then OP should explicitly describe the data structure he is working with. Lets see if he updates his question or not.